# Rails 5: jquery user input data not saving

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form in a Rails app that is posting but not saving the input data.

The service provider has the abilitiy to define different wine sets, which he is offering for example 1,3,6,12 and more general information, which is displayed in the show.html.erb (wine_controller).

## UPDATE

Within the show.html.erb a _form.html.erb is displayed, which uses the reservations_controller.

The logic is that a wine can have many reservations.

Currently the bottles are saved to the db, but the total isn't save to the db, because the Reservations Controller gives a NoMethodError since bottles is an undefined local variable or method.

Wines Controller

```
class WinesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_wine, except: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
  before_action :is_authorised, only: [:details, :pricing, :description, :photo_upload, :more_details, :sets, :location, :update]

  def index
    @wines = current_user.wines
  end

  def new
    @wine = current_user.wines.build
  end

  def create
    @wine = current_user.wines.build(wine_params)
    if @wine.save
      redirect_to details_wine_path(@wine), notice: "Saved..."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong..."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @photos = @wine.photos
    @guest_reviews = @wine.guest_reviews
  end

  def details
  end

  def pricing
  end

  def description
  end

  def photo_upload
    @photos = @wine.photos
  end

  def more_details
  end

  def sets
  end

  def location
  end

  def update

    new_params = wine_params
    new_params = wine_params.merge(active: true) if is_ready_wine

    if @wine.update(wine_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Saved..."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong..."
    end
    redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
  end

  def preload
    today = Date.today
    # Reservations greater than today (upcoming reservations)
    reservations = @wine.reservations.where("start_date >= ?", today)

    render json: reservations
  end


  private
  def set_wine
    @wine = Wine.find(params[:id])
  end
  # Authorize user (current_user == ID 1)
  def is_authorised
    redirect_to root_path, alert: "You don't have permission" unless current_user.id == @wine.user_id
  end

  def is_ready_wine
    !@wine.active && !@wine.price.blank? && !@wine.base_price.blank? && !@wine.wine_name.blank? && !@wine.summary.blank? && !@wine.photos.blank? && !@wine.alcohol.blank? && !@wine.filling.blank? && !@wine.in_stock.blank? && !@wine.address.blank?
  end

  def wine_params
    params.require(:wine).permit(:wine_type, :wine_color, :wine_art, :alcohol, :wine_name, :summary, :address, :is_1, :is_3, :is_6, :is_12, :filling, :base_price, :price, :in_stock, :year, :active)
  end
end
```

Reservation.rb

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :update_financials

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :wine

  def update_financials
    total = wine.price * bottles if wine.present? && bottles.present?
    price = wine.price if wine.present?
  end
end
```

My Helper function for _form.html.erb

```
  def wine_quantity(wine)
    case
    when wine.is_1 && wine.is_3 && wine.is_6 && wine.is_12 then [["1 Flasche", 1], ["3 Flaschen", 3], ["6 Flaschen", 6], ["12 Flaschen", 12]]
    when wine.is_1 && wine.is_3 && wine.is_6 then [["1 Flasche", 1], ["3 Flaschen", 3], ["6 Flaschen", 6]]
    when wine.is_1 && wine.is_3 && wine.is_12 then [["1 Flasche", 1], ["3 Flaschen", 3], ["12 Flaschen", 12]]
    when wine.is_1 && wine.is_6 && wine.is_12 then [["1 Flasche", 1], ["6 Flaschen", 6], ["12 Flaschen", 12]]
    when wine.is_1 && wine.is_12 then [["1 Flasche", 1], ["12 Flaschen", 12]]
    when wine.is_1 && wine.is_6 then [["1 Flasche", 1], ["6 Flaschen", 6]]
    when wine.is_1 && wine.is_3 then [["1 Flasche", 1], ["3 Flaschen", 3]]
    else
      end
    end
```

If the provider chooses to offer 6 and 12 bottles, only 6 and 12 bottles are show in the form.html.erb

My _form.html.erb:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <%= form_for([@wine, @wine.reservations.new]) do |f| %>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <label>Lieferdatum</label>
          <%= f.text_field :start_date, readonly: true, placeholder: "Lieferdatum", class: "form-control datepicker" %>
        </div>
        <!-- BUY SET? -->
        <div class="col-md-12 select" style="margin-top:10px">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Anzahl an Flaschen</label>
            <%= f.select :bottles, wine_quantity(@wine), {}, id: "bottles", prompt: "Auswählen...", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div id="preview" style="display:none">
        <table class="reservation-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Preis pro Flasche</td>
              <td class="text-right"><%= @wine.price %>€</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Anzahl Flaschen</td>
              <td class="text-right">x <span id="reservation_bottles"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="total">Gesamt</td>
              <td class="text-right"><span id="reservation_total"></span>€</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <br/>
      <%= f.submit "Bestellen", id: "btn_book", class: "btn btn-normal btn-block", disabled: true %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

$(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: '<%= preload_wine_path(wine_id: @wine.id) %>',
    dataTyp: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

      var bottles = document.getElementById("bottles").value;
      var total = bottles * <%= @wine.price %>
      $('#reservation_bottles').text(bottles);
      $('#reservation_total').text(total.toFixed(2));

      $('#reservation_start_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: 2,
        maxDate: '5d',
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
          $('#preview').show();
          $('#btn_book').attr('disabled', false);

          $('#bottles').on('click', function() {
          var bottles = $(this).val();
          var total = bottles * <%= @wine.price %>

          $('#reservation_bottles').text(bottles);
          $('#reservation_total').text(total.toFixed(2));

          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

My Reservations Controller:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    wine = Wine.find(params[:wine_id])

    if current_user == wine.user
      flash[:alert] = "Du kannst nicht deinen eigenen Wein kaufen!"
    else

    start_date = Date.parse(reservation_params[:start_date])

    @reservation = current_user.reservations.build(reservation_params)
    @reservation.wine = wine
    @reservation.price = wine.price
    @reservation.total = wine.price * bottles
    @reservation.save

    flash[:notice] = "Erfolgreich Bestellt!"
  end
    redirect_to wine
  end

  def your_orders
    @orders = current_user.reservations.order(start_date: :asc)
    @today = Date.today
  end

  def your_reservations
    @wines = current_user.wines
  end

  # Each Order Details
  def order_details
    @orders = current_user.reservations.order(start_date: :asc)
  end

  private
  def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:start_date)
  end

end
```

When I try to implement :bottles into the reservations_controller.rb, I get a NoMethodError... I think I'm parsing the input data from the form.html.erb to the reservations controller wrong.

Here is the Request:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"3xgM8kSLwa+8JafBZYMoX+BA2XgelWY5bY7yENMrtqAxXCrBb6IabNFa72BG0H6jYnszkzZ/oilOLbka2mmVUA==",
 "reservation"=>{"start_date"=>"26-10-2018", "bottles"=>"3"},
 "commit"=>"Bestellen",
 "wine_id"=>"3"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your ajax is sending the data to a different controller.  isn't it sending it to the 'preload' action of the 'wine' controller?

```
<script>
$(function() {

  $.ajax({
    // updated URL
    url: '<%= reservation_path(wine_id: @wine.id) %>',
    // updated datatype field name
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

      var bottles = document.getElementById("bottles").value;
      var total = bottles * <%= @wine.price %>
      $('#reservation_bottles').text(bottles);
      $('#reservation_total').text(total);

      $('#reservation_start_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: 2,
        maxDate: '5d',
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
          $('#preview').show();
          $('#btn_book').attr('disabled', false);

          $('#bottles').on('click', function() {
          var bottles = $(this).val();
          var total = bottles * <%= @wine.price %>

          $('#reservation_bottles').text(bottles);
          $('#reservation_total').text(total.toFixed(2));

          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

also, create a hidden field in your form for the wine_id; Note: assumes you are using form_for or form_with

```
<%= form.hidden_field :wine_id, @wine.id %>
```

Also looks like your controller isn't accepting the bottles data yet and then you may not be referencing it correctly.  I am assuming your reservation model has a field called bottles that holds integer data.  As such, here's the changes I would propose:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # you don't need to look up the wine to assign it the reservations; skip this
    # wine = Wine.find(params[:wine_id])

    # TBH, I would move this into a validation check
    if current_user == wine.user
      flash[:alert] = "Du kannst nicht deinen eigenen Wein kaufen!"
      # don't you need to render the original page so the user can edit the choice?  something like:
      # render :new
    else

    # what are you using start_date for?  seems like you should remove it
    # start_date = Date.parse(reservation_params[:start_date])

    @reservation = current_user.reservations.build(reservation_params)
    # The math on reservation is more appropriate within the reservations model

    if @reservations.save
      flash[:notice] = "Erfolgreich Bestellt!"
    else
      # handle errors here
    end
  end

 ...

  private

  # you need to add bottles and wine_id to your permitted params
  def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:start_date, :bottles, :wine_id)
  end
end
```

Then modify your Reservations model for the callback

```
class Reservation < ActiveModel
  # use a callback to update the model when fields are changed
  before_save :update_financials
  ...
  def update_financials
    total = wine.price * bottles if wine.present? && bottles.present?
    price = wine.price if wine.present?
  end
end
```

last comment, I would probably move the `current_user == wine.user` into a validation check of reservations.  this is a little more complicated, but simplifies your controller and allows you to test it in your model a lot easier.  see here:  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

Comment: Looks like your ajax is sending the data to a different controller.  isn't it sending it to the 'preload' action of the 'wine' controller? Also, maybe just embed the wine_id into the ajax data submission on reservations. I'm going to update the edits as such

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the provided solution didn't work fully. The ajax is sending the data to the preload action of the wine controller, thats right, since I'm also using a calender in the reservation form, therefore I am using start_date in the reservations_controller.rb. I added the update_financials to the Reservation model and did some other small changes you've suggested. Right now bottles are saved into the db, but the problem is that I can't call wine.bottles in the Reservations Controller and therefore can't calculate the total price. I'm getting a method error...

Comment: How can the reservations controller be called when you are callling the wine controller?

Comment: The user sees the show.html.erb from the Wine Controller, within the show.html.erb the _form.html.erb is rendered from the Reservations Controller, the wines controller shows general information from the wine (vendor), and the reservations controller shows the provided options from the vendor. There is an association between wine and reservations. I'll update my post with the additional information.

Comment: I still don't understand why your ajax url is posting to the wine controller?  isn't it supposed to be posting to the reservations controller?  can you show the entire error and backtrace along with the Request data

Comment: also, if you copy-pasted your code for the view, then you still have a mis-spelling for your ajax`dataType` field (missing the trailing 'e')

Comment: Alright, I think this is getting out of scope. I inserted bottles into the reservation_params and now it gets saved to the db. I'll create a hidden_field for :total and parse the #reservation_total into :total and the total price should also be saved to the db. Is there a way to store the :bottles and :total from the reservation_params into a variable ? Since I'm getting an error when I try @reservation.total = wine.price * wine.bottles

Comment: if total is a field of reservation and you pass total into the database as a reservation_params, then reservation.total will be set when you call `current_user.reservations.build(reservation_params)`